# Symfony - Ajax Select

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, jquery-select2

I am working on a Symfony project where I have a product entity and I need an Ajax search bar to search for through my products and select some of them. The problem is I have a search bar which gives me live results from the database but if I select the product it should show the data in my table. For some reason I am not able to show the selected results in my table.

js

```
 $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
       ajax: {
           url: '/product/api/search',
           dataType: 'json',
      }
 });
```

Controller

```
public function viewActionSearch(Request $request)
{

$query = $request->get('term');

$result = [
    'results' => [],
];

if ($query !== null){
    $products = $this->productRepository->getSearchList($query);

    $result['results'];

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $result['results'][]     = [
            'id' => $product['id'],
            'text' => $product['name'],
        ];
    }

} else {

    $products = $this->productRepository->getResultList(1);
    foreach ($products as $entity) {
        $result['results'][] = [
            'id' => $entity['id'],
            'text' => $entity['name'],
        ];
    }
}

return new JsonResponse($result);

}
```

ProductList

```
public function getPage(Request $request)
    {
        $products = $this->productRepository->getAllProducts($currentPage);

        return $this->render(
            '@app_bar/Product/productList.twig',
            [
                'products' => $products,                   
            ]
        );
    }
```

Twig

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- select2 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme@master/dist/select2-bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container mt-5">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="js-data-example-ajax form-control"></select>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>




<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>SKU</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ product.id }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ product.name }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ product.sku }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ path('app_product_getproduct', {'id': product.id}) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="{{ path('app_product_delete', {'id': product.id}) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I visit the route /product/api/search/ it's giving my a result back but i am not able to show these selected products in my table.

Comment: But you do nothing to show data in your table.

Comment: @u_mulder added the table but the results from the table is not getting from the search api

Comment: How does `ProductList::getPage()` fit in here? Is this another controller action?

Comment: It's also worth noting that it's fine to respond to an AJAX request with server-side rendered HTML, and then insert that into the DOM; e.g: `$.get('some/html', (response) => $('.result').html(response))`—but in this case you would not use `JsonResponse`

Comment: @DarraghEnright what I want to achieve the table with all results to replace with the select product from the select2 ajax call but I do not now how to replace the results with one result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing something here. Symfony does not work like frontend frameworks like vue.js or similar. What you are doing you are rendering serverside request and after that, you just fetch data via AJAX and you do nothing with that data. jQuery needs instructions on what to do with data you get from the server. You can always use Symfony alongside some frontend framework, but you need to understand the difference when serverside renders your twig template and when frontend framework renders it.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Hint:

`$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
       ajax: {
           url: '/product/api/search',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (data) {
             $.each(response, function () {
               $('#mytable').append('<tr><td>' + this.product_name + '</td><td>' + this.product_price + '</td></tr>');
             });
           }
      }
 });`

There are different methods of what you can render, you can reload whole table or just rows that you need.

Comment: Okay could you help me what to do with the data and how?

Comment: You must render a table after you receive a response from the server.
I will edit my answer.

Comment: You select the table with jQuery and you render that table based on data you get from the server. Which part is not clear?

Comment: There is a table with all results which gets the results from the controller. There is also a ajax search bar these results are in json format and i am able to search through it. But once i select a product i am not able to render this to the symfony controller. I do not understand what you mean with you select the table with jquery and render that table based on data you get from the server.

Comment: You receive JSON list of products you want to show on a browser? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. If no results are searched through select2 ajax it should show all results but if the search bar is used and product is selected the result with all results should be replaced with the results of the product/api/search

Comment: You are using word "replaced" it is exactly what you need, so before that you need to render the content you are going to replace table with. Ive edited my answer once more.